# Can't Connect to AWS Cloud9 IDE With Safari

Tags: cookies, safari, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

I'm trying to use Cloud 9 but keep getting the following message during the deployment of the IDE:

```
"Your web browser does not have third-party cookies enabled"
```

I'm using Safari 11.0.3 and in the preferences-privacy the block all cookies box is unchecked.  I can use Chrome but would prefer to use Safari.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to uncheck "Prevent cross-site tracking" to get it to work. Maybe it has something to do with authenticity and AWS passing off to cloud9. I don't remember this being a problem in the past, and I've never had problems logging on to cloud9 directly.

Safari -- Version 11.0.3 (13604.5.100.6)

Comment: Yeah this works, but it (C9) sucks because of it.  Basically weaken your privacy on the entire browser to enable C9.

Comment: Small note: safari needs to be restarted for this to work.

Comment: It's not working with Safari version 13. Any update?

Comment: Not a solution, but logging in with Chrome to the workspace--and then going back to Safari--seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Cloud9 has been updated so that you no longer need to enable third-party cookies to open the IDE.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=7207