# Can't Connect to AWS Cloud9 IDE With Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

Similar to [Can't Connect to AWS Cloud9 IDE With Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356846/cant-connect-to-aws-cloud9-ide-with-safari)

I can't run AWS-C9 on my Google Chrome and keep getting the Environment Error "Your web browser does not have third-party cookies enabled". Under my cookie settings, I already enabled "Allow sites to save and read cookie data" but the error keeps popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the "Block third-party cookies" option

[image]

Or if you want to keep this setting on for security reasons, you can enable third-party cookies only for `amazon.com` and `amazonaws.com`

[image]